# React Native Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am using React native with Typescript, when i run react-native run-android it raises an error shown below[image]

Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: Please don't post images of text like this. Copy the text to your question and use the code format tool

Answer (score 0):

The error does not depends of typescript. As mentioned you need to install Java 11 instead 1.8 to run your project. I guess you run a new version of RN. Take a look to the "get started" section of the RN doc. It is now mentionned to install Java 11.

I suggest you to install it with sdkman if you are on an Unix system. Anyway you should take a look to this [article](https://link.medium.com/5KZsk9DR6ob). You will find some informations about sdkman and set Java 11 for your project in Android studio.